# Facing Issue while starting the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, server

**Hello everyone can anyone help me in resolving this issue because I am facing this issue since morning.**

`app.use("/", require(path.json(__dirname,"routes")));`

The issue is occurring in the above line.

`C:\Users\user\Desktop\fullstack-project-Sumit-malviya-au8\backend\server.js:16`
`app.use("/", require(path.json(__dirname,"routes")));`

```
TypeError: path.json is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\fullstack-project-Sumit-malviya-au8\backend\server.js:16:27)7)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)                                         
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Comment: What is `path.json`? What are you trying to do? Did you mean `path.join`?

Comment: it's still not working when I am using path.join(__dirname, "routes")

Answer (score 0):

`path.json` doesn't exist;
try using `path.join(__dirname, 'routes')`

Comment: Please add an explanation to improve the insight and give the OP some more information

Comment: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\fullstack-project-Sumit-malviya-au8\backend\routes'

code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\fullstack-project-Sumit-malviya-au8\\backend\\server.js'
  ]


Now getting this error when I am using path,join(__dirname, "routes")r